# How to append Values to Excel Range

Tags: c#, excel, worksheet

I have an Excel workbook which has 3 worksheets with a named range defined for address A1:F10 in each sheet and have some values.
I wanted to have a range defined and set all the 3 worksheet range values to this.

Example

TempRange = Test1Range + Test2Range + Test3Range

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
Application.Union(Range1,Range2)
```

Answer (score 1):

IF all four ranges are the same size, then you can add 'em up with an array formula. Select the entire area of "TempRange", and type

```
=Test1Range + Test2Range + Test3Range
```

... and then, to enter it, hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, not plain ENTER.

It's been a long time, and I use OpenOffice these days, so I might have details wrong. The general idea works, though, so even if this exact thing isn't right, googling for "Excel array formula" will probably turn up some helpful information.